# how to zoom any class or id in css3 on hover?

Tags: css

i am now studying css3 but not working class in css3 any one help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoom Hover</title>
        <style type="text/css">

    @-moz-keyframes 'zoom' {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes 'zoom' {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
    }    

.aaa{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;

    }

.aaa:hover {
    -moz-animation-name: 'zoom' 2s;
}
.aaa:hover {
    -webkit-animation: 'zoom' 2s;
}
.aaa{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s; /* firefox */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* chrome, safari */
    -o-transition-duration: 2s; /* opera */
    -ms-transition-duration: 2s; /* ie 9 */
}
.aaa:hover {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="aaa"style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any way to do this any one assist me please, is there any
website for css3 for learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to "*zoom*" an element using CSS you should use a transformation and scale it to the size you want:

```
transform: scale(2);
```

This will scale the element and all of its content by a factor of 2.

Here's a fully working example:

**CSS**

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;    
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;    
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.test:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/gCdhY/) (using transform and scale)

What you tried to do, was to change the dimensions of an element. That won't actually zoom the element but make it larger. Child-elements are not affected by this. You can achieve this easier by using a transition instead of an animation:

**CSS**

```
.test:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/gtPrQ/) (using transition)